# What is the difference between the following two xpath expressions?

Tags: xml, xpath

If the expression `//*` is equivelant to the following expression `/descendant-or-self::*` and it returns all the elements in the xml document.

So why exists difference between

1. **`/a//*`** (that does not returns `a` element)

and

2. **`/a/descendant-or-self::*`** (which returns also `a` element)

Why `/a//*` does not returns also `a` element itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//` is actually short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` (note the trailing slash!), hence `//*` is actually short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/*` See https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev

So, from your example, `/a//*` actually means `/a/descendant-or-self::node()/*`, which is equivalent to `/a/descendant::*`, and is not the same as `/a/descendant-or-self::*`